# Trouble with adding swipe for boostrap tabs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, tabs

I have two bootstrap tabs in my website, each tab contains loop of dynamic images in a grid. Client wants in the mobile version, users should be able to swipe between these two tabs.

I tried adding jqqeury touch swipe to my existing code following this example: https://codepen.io/rjrana/pen/OmKezK

Below is my code, could you some one please help out whats the issue its not working? it console logs swipe left or swipe right correctly tho.

Html code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" integrity="sha384-JvExCACAZcHNJEc7156QaHXTnQL3hQBixvj5RV5buE7vgnNEzzskDtx9NQ4p6BJe" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="change-lives">
        {{ __('home.we_change_lives') }}
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false">
                {{ __('home.celebrities') }}
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab3" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab3" aria-selected="false">
                {{ __('home.testimonials') }}
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="gallery-row">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="gallery-row">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
@if(app()->getlocale() == 'ar')
<script src="{{ asset('https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}" integrity="sha384-40ix5a3dj6/qaC7tfz0Yr+p9fqWLzzAXiwxVLt9dw7UjQzGYw6rWRhFAnRapuQyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@else
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
@endif
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.18/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery-wrapper").swipe({
        swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            console.log("Swiped left");
            $(".nav.nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link.active").next('li').find('a').tab('show');
        },
        swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            console.log("Swiped right");
            $(".nav.nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link.active").prev('li').find('a').tab('show');
        },
    });
});



</script>
```